# Find the SkyDNS ip and port in kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Within the Kubernetes cluster which enables SkyDNS (Google Container Engine), how can I find the IP:PORT of the SkyDNS?

I want to add that DNS server to NODE's `resolve.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `kubectl cluster-info` it will list the proxy endpoints for the cluster addon services. E.g.

```
$ kubectl cluster-info 
Kubernetes master is running at https://104.196.10.55
GLBCDefaultBackend is running at https://104.196.10.55/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/default-http-backend
KubeDNS is running at https://104.196.10.55/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
```

If you're looking for the specific IP:PORT of the pods:

```
$ kubectl get endpoints kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
NAME       ENDPOINTS                     AGE
kube-dns   10.244.1.3:53,10.244.1.3:53   10d
```

But be aware that that will change if pods are restarted for any reason.